# Nonces and web developer toolbar in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, security

Symfony uses nonces in the development web toolbar like this :

```
<div id="sfwdtd61de8" class="sf-toolbar sf-display-none"></div><script 
nonce=ca6666b27bc9c402c16192e4b43bbdaa>
```

etc and then, since the nonces are dynamically generated, i can't use in my vhost this kind of code for Content Security Policy :

```
Header set Content-Security-Policy script-src 'self' 'nonce-
ca6666b27bc9c402c16192e4b43bbdaa'
```

So what am i supposed to do in order to whitelist the web developer toolbar code ?

I'm using :

- Symfony 3.3.2
- Apache 2.4.25
- PHP 7.1.2

Comment: I don't know if you found a workaround, but I ended using https://github.com/nelmio/NelmioSecurityBundle

Comment: It's been a long time since I worked on this project and I'm running out of time those days. The link is interesting that said, although I would have avoided using any wrapper just for this detail.

Comment: Yea I understand. I had hard time making my website csp complient with all the directives I needed, the bundle was great for that. But maybe overkill if it's only for sf toolbar.

Answer (score 1):

Create a subscriber:

```
namespace App\EventSubscriber;

use Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventSubscriberInterface;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\ResponseEvent;
use Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\KernelEvents;
use Symfony\Component\Security\Csrf\TokenGenerator\TokenGeneratorInterface;

class NonceSubscriber implements EventSubscriberInterface
{
    private $tokenGenerator;
    
    public function __construct( TokenGeneratorInterface $tokenGenerator ) 
    {
        $this->tokenGenerator = $tokenGenerator;
    }
    
    public function onKernelResponse(ResponseEvent $event)
    {    
        $response = $event->getResponse();

        $token_CSRF = $this->tokenGenerator->generateToken();
        
        $response->headers->set
        (
            'Content-Security-Policy', "script-src nonce-".$token_CSRF."';"
        );
    }

    public static function getSubscribedEvents()
    {
        return [
            KernelEvents::RESPONSE => 'onKernelResponse',
        ];
    }
}
```

After this you will see your nonce `$token_CSRF` together with the nonce generated by the WebProfilerBundle in the response headers.